# PHP chmod reports success when it has not worked - why?

Tags: php

I have tried this:

```
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($mdbFilename)), -4).'<br />';
echo chmod($mdbFilename, 0777);
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($mdbFilename)), -4).'<br />';
```

The out put I get for the above is:

```
0666
1
0666
```

So the above has not worked! Why is this the case? And why does chmod report true?

The variable `$mdbFilename` contains the path to the file which is `C:\wamp\www\webs\db\access_db_1276264459.mdb`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does not support the *NIX [octal permissions](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod).

***Edit:*** You may also want to try [clearing the stat cache](http://www.php.net/clearstatcache) before you re-read the file's permissions, ala Pekka's response.

**Edit #2:** Since a permission of `0777` specifies that the file is executable, why would you even want to do that to the file?

It's an MDB file, or a Microsoft Access<sup>™</sup> database file. Why would that ever need to be executed? I think Windows determines whether something is executable by its having an executable extension (like `.EXE`, `.BAT`, or `.COM`).

Comment: Ah, this is on Windows. That's the solution then. +1

Comment: I think it does work - It seemed to have worked for this commentor on php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php#72419 ??

Comment: @Abs: `0777` is read (`4`) + write (`2`) + execute (`1`) for user, group, and others.  The Windows version is probably configured to return `0444` for read-only files and `0666` for read/write files.

Comment: Actually, it seems more people say that it doesn't work and once person says it works in the comments. I'll have to come up with something else. Thanks.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Most of the time Windows also allows execution of any file, so it would be `0777` for read-write and `0555` for read-only.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** I overlooked that the OP is on Windows, where there is no chmod as such. I'm leaving the answer in place because if this were on Linux, I think it would apply.

**Old answer:**  Try adding a [`clearstatcache()`](http://www.php.net/clearstatcache) call between every line.